# Dont show me again message with react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, modal-dialog, local-storage

I have modal which shows when user visit my page now I want a user to be able to hide this modal so that doesn't show the modal again using local storage or cookies

Here is a live demo on code sandbox : [dont show me again](https://codesandbox.io/s/dont-show-me-again-kojtx?file=/src/index.js)

Js code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Modal from "./Modal";
import useModal from "./useModal";

import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const { isShowing, toggle } = useModal();
  const [cookieConsent, showCookieConsent] = useState(true);
  const [checked, setIsChecked] = useState(0);

  const handleOnchange = (e) => {
    setIsChecked(e.target.value);
  };
  let modalStorage = localStorage.setItem("hide", checked);

  useEffect(() => {
    toggle();
    if (modalStorage) {
      showCookieConsent(false);
    }
  }, []);

  const clearStorage = () => {
    localStorage.clear();
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={clearStorage}> Clear Storage</button>
      {cookieConsent === false && (
        <Modal
          isShowing={isShowing}
          handleOnchange={handleOnchange}
          hide={toggle}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Now when I click the checkbox and close the modal and I refresh the page it shows again instead of hiding it

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `let modalStorage = localStorage.setItem("hide", checked)`, it's supposed to be `getItem`

Comment: so I don't need to set it first?

Comment: There are many problems with your current implementation: 1. you are setting the localStorage entry on every render `localStorage.setItem("hide", checked)`. You should only set it when the user closes the dialog. 2. You never read the localStorage value. You should read it when initializing your state. 3. You have two flags to control if the dialog is visible but the logic about them is utterly confused: upon the first render you toggle and set both those flags to some different value. Why did you not initialize them to the desired value in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed a few things

```
const handleOnchange = (e) => {
    setIsChecked(e.target.checked);
    localStorage.setItem("hide", e.target.checked)
};
  
useEffect(() => {
    toggle();
    let modalStorage = localStorage.getItem("hide", checked);
    if (modalStorage) {
      showCookieConsent(false);
    }
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used a custom hook to solve a similar issue. Sharing the code in case it helps anyone.

```js
// useInfoBanner.jsx
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { getFromLocalStorage, setToLocalStorage } from "utils/storage";

const useInfoBanner = (key) => {
  const [showInfoBanner, setShowInfoBanner] = useState(false);

  const handleHideInfoBanner = () => {
    setShowInfoBanner(false);
    setToLocalStorage(key, true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const isHideInfoBanner = getFromLocalStorage(key);
    isHideInfoBanner ? setShowInfoBanner(false) : setShowInfoBanner(true);
  }, []);

  return [showInfoBanner, handleHideInfoBanner];
};

export default useInfoBanner;

// utils/storage.js
export const getFromLocalStorage = key =>JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
export const setToLocalStorage = (key, value) =>
  localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));

// You can use this in your components like so
  const [showInfoBanner, handleHideInfoBanner] = useInfoBanner("hideSettingsInfoBanner");

//.. then in return

{showInfoBanner && <InfoBanner />}
```